Set diagnostics configuration per LSP
I have the following in my config
vim.diagnostic.config {
  virtual_text = false,
  underline = false,
  update_in_insert = false,
  float = {
    focusable = false,
    style = 'minimal',
    border = 'rounded',
    header = '',
    prefix = '',
  },
}

which works as expected. I'd like to enable the virtual_text and underline for certain LSP specifically though. Is there a way to specific the config per LSP?

Set the config in your LSP's on_attach function.

You could define an autocommand depending on your filetype to modify your LSP configuration.
For example, to enable virtual_text and underline only for Python filetype:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('BufRead', {
    group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('filetype_python', { clear = true }),
    desc = 'Set LSP diagnostics for Python',
    pattern = { '*.py' },
    callback = function()
      vim.diagnostic.config({
        virtual_text = true,
        underline = true,
      })
    end,
  })

